# modificacion array php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I need to modify this array so that I stayed in a more friendly way and can use it better I have this

```
$res = [
                "DATA DOCUMENT:",
                "Countrydocument: CO",
                "Person type: Natural",
                "Document type: Cédula Ciudadanía",
                "Document number: 1121212121",
                "Name: JOSE CRUZ",
                "Other Information: \ n"
            ],
            [
                "DATA DOCUMENT:",
                "Countrydocument: CO",
                "Person type: Natural",
                "Document type: Cédula Ciudadanía",
                "Document number: 1121212121",
                "Name: JOSE CRUZ",
                "Other Information: \ n"
            ]
            ];




and I want it like that

         $resultado =[
            "DATOS DOCUMENTO:",
            "País documento"=> "CO",
            "Tipo persona" => "Natural",
            "Tipo documento"=> "Cédula Ciudadanía",
            "Número documento"=> "11103",
            "Nombre"=> " CRUZ",
            "Otra Información:\n"
        ],
        [
            "DATOS DOCUMENTO:",
            "País documento"=> "CO",
            "Tipo persona" => "Natural",
            "Tipo documento"=> "Cédula Ciudadanía",
            "Número documento"=> "111",
            "Nombre"=> " CRUZ",
            "Otra Información:\n"
        ]
        ];
```

I look for my array is like more friendly to work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA1gZ.png)

Comment: Can you explain why `explode` is not acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 

$res = [
    "DATA DOCUMENT:",
    "Countrydocument: CO",
    "Person type: Natural",
    "Document type: Cédula Ciudadanía",
    "Document number: 1121212121",
    "Name: JOSE CRUZ",
    "Other Information: \ n"
];
$newRes = [];
array_walk($res, function($value) use(&$newRes){

    $data = explode(":", $value);
    $newRes[trim($data[0])] = trim($data[1]) ?? null;
});
```

If you want to avoid explode then you can use regex :

```
array_walk($res, function($value) use(&$newRes){

    $data = preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)[0];
    $newRes[trim($data[1])] = trim($data[2]) ?? null;
});
```

Comment: So next time don't say no explode in your question